# Как сложить дату и время?

Tags: c#, время, дата

Есть две переменные (дергаю из базы). Одна - дата, вторая - время. Как их сложить в один `datetime`

Comment: Посмотрите TimeSpan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считать время в `TimeSpan`-объект и через метод `DateTime.Add(TimeSpan`) передать в экземпляр даты. Ну или там перегружено сложение =)

```
DateTime date = ...;
TimeSpan time = ...;

date += time;
```